# Salvar mais de um dado neste formulário com PHP e MySQLi

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Olá, estou com um problema neste código. Estou fazendo um formulário que preciso para salvar, mas infelizmente no banco de dados apenas salva uma vez o resto sempre dá erro...Gostaria de solucionar este problema, desde já agradeço por ter lido.
Abaixo contém a primeira parte do código

```
<?php
   session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Formulário</title>
</head>
  <body>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset ($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="registroCPP.php">
      <input type="text" name="Nome" id="Nome" placeholder="Nome"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="Sobrenome" id="Sobrenome" placeholder="Sobrenome"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="E-mail"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="Idade" id="Idade" placeholder="Idade"/></br>
      <input type="text" name="Celular" id="Celular" placeholder="Número de Celular"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="Endereco" id="Endereco" placeholder="Endereço"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="numero_endereco" id="numero_endereco" placeholder="Número"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="complemento" id="complemento" placeholder="Complemento"/><br>
      <input type="text" name="cargo" id="cargo" placeholder="Cargo/ Emprego"/><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Envie">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

A parte que recebe os dados deste submit:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conecta_mysql.ini';

$nome = $_POST['Nome']; 
$sobrenome = $_POST['Sobrenome'];
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$idade = $_POST['Idade'];
$celular =  $_POST['Celular'];
$endereco =  $_POST['Endereco'];
$numend = $_POST['numero_endereco'];
$complemento = $_POST['complemento'];
$cargo =  $_POST['cargo'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (Nome, Sobrenome, Email, Idade, Celular, Endereço, NumeroEndereco, ComplementoEndereco, Cargo) VALUES ('$nome','$sobrenome','$email','$idade','$celular', '$endereco', '$numend', '$complemento', '$cargo')";
if($conexao->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $_SESSION ['msg'] = "Usuário cadastrado";
    header('Location: formulario.php');
}else{
    echo "erro";
}
$conexao->close();

?>
```

A última parte do código que é a conexão com o banco de dados.

```
<?php

$conexao = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','iep');

mysqli_set_charset($conexao, 'utf8');

if($conexao -> connect_error){
    die("Falha ao realizar a conexão: ".$conexao -> connect_error);
}?>
```

Comment: Qual o erro que dá?

Comment: Talvez no seu banco de dados a chave primária da tabela 'usuário' não esteja definida como AUTO_INCREMENT. Já verificou isso?

Comment: Eu conferi o banco de dados, e realmente não tinha definido. Agora deu tudo certo, grato LauBF

Answer (score 2):

Amigo como você está utilizando apenas o php tanto ele separado quanto ele dentro do html pelas session seu código fica "pobre", dessa maneira você não consegue fazer a validação dos dados corretamente.

Recomento que utilize ajax para chamar o php, você vai ter mais liberdade para tratar o retorno do php.